# Conversion from SYSTEMTIME to time_t gives out Time in UTC/GMT

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, time, mfc

I am trying to convert `SYSTEMTIME` to `time_t` through the implementation I found in various forums.

```
time_t TimeFromSystemTime(const SYSTEMTIME * pTime)
{
    struct tm tm;
    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));

    tm.tm_year = pTime->wYear - 1900; // EDIT 2 : 1900's Offset as per comment
    tm.tm_mon = pTime->wMonth - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = pTime->wDay;

    tm.tm_hour = pTime->wHour;
    tm.tm_min = pTime->wMinute;
    tm.tm_sec = pTime->wSecond;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1; // Edit 2: Added as per comment

    return mktime(&tm);
}
```

But to my surprise, the `tm` is carrying the data corresponds to the local time but the `mktime()` returns the `time_t` corresponds to the time in UTC.

Is this the way it works or am I missing anything here?

Thanks for the help in advance !!

EDIT 1: I want to convert the `SYSTEMTIME` which carries my Local time as the `time_t` exactly.

I am using this in the VC6 based MFC application.

EDIT 2: Modified Code.

Comment: Yes, the manual says that mktime() converts from local time to UTC.  As required by time_t, it stores the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, 12am UTC.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: use _mkgmtime() which just does a conversion between the two without taking timezones into acount.

Comment: Your explanation is somewhat confusing: what does the SYSTEMTIME contain? local time or UTC time ?

Comment: SYSTEMTIME is always local time.

Comment: Then `mktime` does what you want with 2 caveats: the C library's notion of the time zone must be in sync with that of the system, and the `tm_isdst` flag in the `tm` structure must be set properly.  Check for a similar field in the `SYSTEMTIME` structure.

Comment: Also check if the `SYSTEMTIME` structure's `wYear` field is the number of years since 1900 as expected for the `tm_year` field.

Comment: @hans-passant, it is not stated how the SYSTEMTIME his function receives is obtained. As it is a stuct, it could have ben populated with any time value and so not necesarilly is in local time. All he wants is to convert between the two representations.

Comment: @Paul No Paul. The SYSTEMTIME is populated legally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the Solution from the Windows SDK, through [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [_timezone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htb3tdkc.aspx)

```
time_t GetLocaleDateTime( time_t ttdateTime) // The time_t from the mktime() is fed here as the Parameter
{
    if(ttdateTime <= 0)
        return 0;

    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzi;

    GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzi); // We can also use the StandardBias of the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION

    int iTz = -_timezone; // Current Timezone Offset from UTC in Seconds

    iTz = (iTz >  12*3600) ? (iTz - 24*3600) : iTz; // 14  ==> -10
    iTz = (iTz < -11*3600) ? (iTz + 24*3600) : iTz; // -14 ==> 10

    ttdateTime += iTz;

    return ttdateTime;
}
```

**EDIT 1**:
Please do add your comments, and also if you see any bugs feel free to comment or edit. Thanks.